# Access violation for Linked List Nodes: C++

Tags: c++

Need help writing a program for an airline reservation system that inputs and outputs the first name, last name, flight number, and boarding priority (Platinum, Gold, Silver, or Lead). The professor wants it done for a max of 10 passengers. This is the code I've written up so far.

It lets me enter in the information but once I type "D" to display it out, the program exits and I'm given the error: Access violation reading location 0x00000004

I'm not sure why this is happening and any help is appreciated.
    #include

```
using namespace std;

class airPassenger
{
    struct passengerInfo
    {
        int     fltNum;
        char    fName[10];
        char    lName[10];
        enum    priority { Platinium, Gold, Silver, Lead };
        passengerInfo *next = NULL;
    };
    passengerInfo* head;

public:
    airPassenger() { head = NULL; };
    passengerInfo               maxPassengers[10];
    passengerInfo::priority     passengerP;
    void addNode();
    void topMenu();
    void displayList();
};
```

This is the .cpp file:

```
int main() {
    airPassenger obj;

    obj.topMenu();
    return 0;
}

void airPassenger::addNode()
{
    passengerInfo* newNode, *nodePtr;
    newNode = new passengerInfo;
    char priority_Response;
    int priorty_Response1;

    cout << "\nPassenger First Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> newNode->fName;

    cout << "\nPassenger Last Name: ";
    cin >> newNode->lName;

    cout << "\nFlight Number: ";
    cin >> newNode->fltNum;

    do {
        cout << "\nPriority: ";
        cout << "\n\t(P)latinium\n";
        cout << "\t(G)old\n";
        cout << "\t(S)ilver\n";
        cout << "\t(L)ead\n";
        cin >> priority_Response;
    } while ((priority_Response != 'P') && (priority_Response != 'p') && (priority_Response != 'G') && (priority_Response != 'g') && (priority_Response != 'S') && (priority_Response != 's') && (priority_Response != 'L') && (priority_Response != 'l'));

    if (priority_Response == 'P' || priority_Response == 'p')
        {
            newNode->Platinium;
            //priorty_Response1 = 0;
        }
        else if (priority_Response == 'G' || priority_Response == 'g')
        {
            newNode->Gold;
            //priorty_Response1 = 1;
        }
        else if (priority_Response == 'S' || priority_Response == 's')
        {
            newNode->Silver;
            //priorty_Response1 = 2;
        }
        else if (priority_Response == 'L' || priority_Response == 'l')
        {
            newNode->Lead;
            //priorty_Response1 = 3;
        }
    else
        {
            priorty_Response1 = -1;
        }

    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next)
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
    system("cls");
}

void airPassenger::displayList()
{
    passengerInfo* nodePtr;
    nodePtr = head;

    //while (nodePtr != NULL)
    //{
            cout << "\nFName: " << nodePtr->fName << endl;
            cout << "LName: " << nodePtr->lName << endl;
            cout << "Flt Num: " << nodePtr->fltNum << endl;
            if (nodePtr->Platinium)
            {
                cout << "Priority: Platinium\n";
            }
            else if (nodePtr->Gold)
            {
                cout << "Priority: Gold\n";
            }
            else if (nodePtr->Silver)
            {
                cout << "Priority: Silver\n";
            }
            else if (nodePtr->Lead)
            {
                cout << "Priority: Lead\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "None of the above.\n";
            }
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        //}

            /*switch (response[i])
            {
            case passengerInfo::Platinium:
                cout << "Priority: Platinium\n";
                break;
            case passengerInfo::Gold:
                cout << "Priority: Gold\n";
                break;
            case passengerInfo::Silver:
                cout << "Priority: Silver\n";
                break;
            case passengerInfo::Lead:
                cout << "Priority: Lead\n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "None of the above.\n";
                break;
            }*/
        cout << endl;

}

void airPassenger::topMenu()
{
    airPassenger passenger;
    int priorty_Response1[10];
    int counter = 0;
    char usr_Response = 'A';
    char priority_Response[10];

    while (usr_Response != 'Q' && usr_Response != 'q')
    {
        cout << "(E)nter the passenger information" << endl;
        cout << "(D)isplay the passenger information" << endl;
        cout << "(Q)uit the program" << endl;

        cout << "Which option would you like?: ";
        cin >> usr_Response;
        if (usr_Response == 'E' || usr_Response == 'e')
        {
            passenger.addNode();
            //cout << "\nPassenger First Name: ";
            //cin >> maxPassengers[counter].fName;

            //cout << "\nPassenger Last Name: ";
            //cin >> maxPassengers[counter].lName;

            //cout << "\nFlight Number: ";
            //cin >> counter;
            //cin >> maxPassengers[counter].fltNum[counter];

            /*cout << "\nPriority: ";
            cout << "\n\t(P)latinium\n";
            cout << "\t(G)old\n";
            cout << "\t(S)ilver\n";
            cout << "\t(L)ead\n";
            cin >> priority_Response[counter];
            if (priority_Response[counter] == 'P' || priority_Response[counter] == 'p')
            {
                priorty_Response1[counter] = 0;
            }
            else if (priority_Response[counter] == 'G' || priority_Response[counter] == 'g')
            {
                priorty_Response1[counter] = 1;
            }
            else if (priority_Response[counter] == 'S' || priority_Response[counter] == 's')
            {
                priorty_Response1[counter] = 2;
            }
            else if (priority_Response[counter] == 'L' || priority_Response[counter] == 'l')
            {
                priorty_Response1[counter] = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                priorty_Response1[counter] = -1;
            }
            counter++;
            system("CLS");*/
        }
        else if (usr_Response == 'D' || usr_Response == 'd')
        {
            displayList();
        }
        cin.ignore();
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger to step through your code line by line to detect the source of the problem? If so, where is it? If not, you should've done that before posting. Also, we don't need all of that code. Please provide a [mcve], with an empashise on the *Minimal* part.

Comment: Yes I did us a debugger and according to that, it  says "error reading character of strings" for the fName and lName and also "unable to read memory" for fltNum and next. Sorry about the extra code

Comment: Don't be sorry for adding too much code - everybody started some day. What you now need to do is to *divide and conquer*. Get rid of some code. If the error persists, get rid of some more. Eventually, the error will go away. Go back one step. Now, you pretty much extracted the error. You created a minimal example. You need to do that now :)

Comment: Still persists..

Comment: But did you do what I've told you to do? Did you *divide and conquer* your code to locate the problem? If so, exctract it and post a [mcve]. Let me stress this once again - **Minimal**.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to read heap memory you are not allowed to. Why do you comment out the while loop? Also, why do you not check in `displayList` if the head pointer is nullptr?

Comment: I commented out the while loop to see where the error was coming from because it looked like the program was not entering the while loop at all. I get the "Access violation reading location 0x00000004" on the first fName cout in that function so I assume the error is there. Not sure how to fix